# Touchpad has been acting crazy since upgrade to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, mouse, touchpad

I have an Asus UX21-A laptop, and recently upgraded from Ubuntu 17.10 to Ubuntu 18.04. In Ubuntu 17.10, my touchpad worked perfectly.

Since upgrading to 18.04, the touchpad behaviour has been very erratic. For example, sometimes when I touch down in a new text area to position the cursor, the contents of my clipboard will get pasted even though I have not selected any paste action. Sometimes when I try dragging something from one window to another, the mouse gets stuck half way. Sometimes it's unresponsive entirely.

So far as I know, I haven't manually set any configurations or intentionally changed relevant to the touchpad since having 17.10.

How do I diagnose and fix the problem with my touchpad behaving strangely?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed the same issues, in particular I suffer most from mouse pointer being stuck while dragging, I have to release my touchpad and after a 1-1.5 seconds it gets back to normal. I have Asus Q500A, first I have upgraded from 17.10 to 18.4, then because of this and some other issues I made a fresh install of 18.4, and right out of the box with no apps installed or configuration changes I have noticed the same issue with touchpad, while other issues gone. So, something doesn't seem right with touchpad handling in 18.4.

In 17.10 I was able to configure my touchpad sensitivity as described here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad, but after upgrade there is no "Synaptics Finger" property left, and in case it can help, here is the output of my xinput --watch-props:

```
alex@Q500A:~$ xinput --watch-props 13
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
        Device Enabled (142):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Tapping Enabled (279): 1
        libinput Tapping Enabled Default (280): 0
        libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (281):    1
        libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (282):    1
        libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (283):       0
        libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (284):       0
        libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (285):  1, 0
        libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (286):  1, 0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (287):       0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (288):       0
        libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (289):    1
        libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (290):    1
        libinput Scroll Methods Available (291):        1, 1, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled (292):   1, 0, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (293):   1, 0, 0
        libinput Click Methods Available (294): 1, 1
        libinput Click Method Enabled (295):    1, 0
        libinput Click Method Enabled Default (296):    1, 0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (297):        0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (298):        0
        libinput Accel Speed (299):     0.000000
        libinput Accel Speed Default (300):     0.000000
        libinput Left Handed Enabled (301):     0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (302):     0
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (264):     1, 1
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (265):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (266):        0, 0
        Device Node (267):      "/dev/input/event5"
        Device Product ID (268):        2, 14
        libinput Drag Lock Buttons (303):       <no items>
        libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (304):       1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please don't use the answer field to say you have that problem. When you have enough reputation, you can upvote the question or add a bounty to attract more attention.

Comment: oops, thanks for letting me know, it was my first posting on askubuntu so I'm not yet familiar with the rules, I thought I'd be good to add extra info and show that the issue is not specific to one user. I'll follow your advise though ;)